# How to use for_each with iterator in dynamic block in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, iterator, terraform

I am trying to do this basically:

```
module "california" {
  source = "./themodule"
  # ...
}

module "oregon" {
  source = "./themodule"
  # ...
}

resource "aws_globalaccelerator_endpoint_group" "world" {
  # ...
  dynamic "endpoint_configuration" {
    for_each = [
      module.california.lb,
      module.oregon.lb
    ]
    iterator = lb
    content {
      endpoint_id = lb.arn
      weight = 100
    }
  }
}

# themodule/main.tf
resource "aws_lb" "lb" {
  # ...
}

output "lb" {
  value = aws_lb.lb
}
```

I am outputting `lb` from a submodule in Terraform, and trying to use that in the parent module in a `for_each` array, with a custom `iterator` name. It is giving me this error:

```
This object does not have an attribute named "arn".
```

But it DOES have that attribute, it's an [`aws_lb`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb). What am I doing wrong in the usage of this `for_each` and module setup, and how do I fix it? Thank you very much!

- https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-rich-value-types/

If I change it to this it seems to work:

```
resource "aws_globalaccelerator_endpoint_group" "world" {
  listener_arn = aws_globalaccelerator_listener.world.id

  endpoint_configuration {
    endpoint_id = module.california.lb.arn
    weight = 100
  }
}
```

Comment: The iterator lb will have only key and value attributes. Thus maybe you have to use `lb.value["arn"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html):

> The iterator object (setting in the example above) has **two attributes**:
>
> **key** is the map key or list element index for the current element. If the for_each expression produces a set value then key is identical to value and should not be used.
>
> **value** is the value of the current element.

Based on that, in the `content`, you should used `lb.value["arn"]`, as per [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks). Thus, the following could be tried:

```
    content {
      endpoint_id = lb.value["arn"]
      weight = 100
    }
```